# Какие страницы просмотренны сегодня счетчик/статистика?

Tags: wordpress

Дорогие друзья подскажите адекватный-легкий-бесплатный плагин вордпресс 
который в админке/консоли сайта вордпресс будет отображать

1.-какие страницы   2.-сколько раз   3.-с каких ip были просмотрены сегодня/7дн/1мес

Comment: Чем не устраивает поиск в wp.org?

Comment: ... что  wp.org?